# javascript two variables with same name co-exist in same object?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'm trying my best to understand javascript. Here is a simple experiment in Chrome console which gets me very confused:

```
var foo=function(){this.p=1;}
foo.prototype.p=2;
var bar=new foo();
//foo{p:1,p:2} <- this is the output of Chrome console, from the last command above
```

The output of Chrome is what confuses me. It seems like bar is an object with 2 parameters, p:1 and p:2. Does this mean bar has 2 p??? What is the reasoning behind this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome DevTools console's inline (non-extended) object representation currently does not display any difference between own properties and inherited prototype properties.

Now let's break what's going on into smaller steps.

`new foo()` creates a new object whose internal `proto` property points to `foo.prototype`. This means this object can access all properties defined in `foo.prototype`. It's called [prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain).

Now when you set a property of the same name in the object, it "shadows" the prototype's property by the same name, turning the latter inaccessible through regular property access (see @loxxy's answer using `Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)` to access the shadowed prototype property).

Once you add a function to the object or its prototype, the console allows you to display the extended object representation, which does differ own properties from prototype properties. In the next example I've added a `q` method to the prototype to allow this behavior. The properties inherited from the prototype are shown inside the object's `proto` internal property:

[image]

---

If you just want to have the number of instanced objects in the constructor's prototype, you can use:

```
var foo = function() {
    Object.getPrototypeOf(this).p++;
}
foo.prototype.p = 0;

console.log(new foo()); //{p: 1}
console.log(new foo()); //{p: 2}
```

Or without the ES5 dependency:

```
var foo = function() {
    foo.prototype.p++;
}
foo.prototype.p = 0;

console.log(new foo()); //{p: 1}
console.log(new foo()); //{p: 2}
```

Comment: Thanks! So is it possible to access the p in __proto__? In the console it seems impossible

Comment: @XunYang Yes, @loxxy's answer does that. `=]`

Comment: Alright, so if "p" is a method, I can "override" it in foo by calling `Object.getPrototypeOf(bar).p()`? Can it be done easier?

Comment: @XunYang Sorry, not sure if I understood what you meant. You want to redefine a prototype property from inside an object instantiation? In case you just want to "override" (I've removed this word from the answer because it sounds too much Java'ish `:P`) the inherited `p` property in `bar`, what you've done is good enough.

Comment: Like this: `foo=function(){this.p=function(){return parent.p()+1;}};`,`foo.prototype.p=function(){return 0;}` Not really for a counter, just an example of "classical" overriding :)

Comment: @XunYang You're making an instantiation object count? Or making an function to return an "id" (number) of the instanced object?

Comment: @XunYang Not sure what you're after but parent suggests you want to inherit override and call the super functions (as it's called in Java I think). Prototype is not really the parent of an object but when you inherit from an object called Parent you do add Parent.prototype to the Child.prototype (inheriting) and you take the instance variables of Parent by calling `Parent.apply(this,arguments);` in the Child function body. You can override functions of Parent and call it's prototype functions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

Comment: @HMR Very interesting read, though I believe OP means Constructor.prototype -> instance instead of Parent Constructor -> Child Constructor.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Aha, maybe Xun wants to shadow the prototype function in the instance and then call it's prototype version from the shadowing function. I don't see a practical use for it as it forces you to create functions for each instance that do the same thing (use inheritance instead) but `__proto__` has been mentioned before if you just want to access it. (instance.`__proto__`.p()+1) In the Hamster example (post in my previous comment) it shows how to override and partly implement Parent methods with the getSpeed method.

Comment: @HMR yes, in that case it'd be easier to just copy the current value from the prototype to the instance.

Answer (score 2):

The bar object has only one p with value 1

The earlier p with value 2 can be viewed in a readonly object which you can access with [getPrototypeOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf):

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(bar).p
```

You see both because the developer toolbar is designed to print an XML representation of the specified object which should intuitively show all the properties, whether directly  accessible or not.

Comment: sure, but why do both appear in the console log?

Comment: a prototype is not read-only, even though you don't normally write to it

Comment: @JanDvorak when you invoke `bar` chrome prints an XML representation of the specified object which should intuitively contain both p's. prototype is not readonly but in this case the reference to prototype exists as readonly or as the non recommended `__proto__`

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Sort of.

`bar` has both:

- A `p` property of its [own](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty).

  ```
  bar.hasOwnProperty('p'); // true
  bar.p;                   // 1
  ```
- A `p` property still remaining [on the `prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) that it *has* through inheritance.

  ```
  Object.getPrototypeOf(bar).p; // 2
  ```

Though, only 1 of them is accessible directly from `bar` at a time, with preference to the *own* property.

```
bar.p;        // 1
delete bar.p;
bar.p;        // 2
```

And, Chrome is showing both because it's traversing the [prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) and looking for any enumerable properties.

Comment: Thank you! And you can't delete p from the prototype?

Comment: @XunYang You can, but not *through* `bar` -- `delete foo.prototype.p`

Answer (score 1):

`var foo=function(){this.p=1;}` is constructor and executes after `var bar=new foo();`. So at the beginning p=2 and then p becomes 1. So:

```
var foo=function(){
   // here this.p is equal to 2
   this.p=1;
   // here this.p is equal to 1
}
foo.prototype.p=2;
var bar=new foo();
```

EDIT:

```
JSON.stringify(bar);
```

Comment: Hi karaxuna, so you mean there can only be one "p" inside object bar?

Comment: @XunYang see this: `JSON.stringify(bar);`

Comment: go in chrome's console and type: `console.dir(bar)`. You'll see in the _ _ proto _ _ the hirarchie. You do **overloading** here

Comment: Thanks! These tools come very handy :)

Comment: @jsmorph Overloading usually means a function/operator which performs different operations depending on the type and number of arguments or operands. I believe overriding is more suitable here.

Answer (score 1):

When you acces a property, the javascript engine will seek it on the object instance, then on all its prototype chain.
So the meaning of p as a prototype property is to have a default value for p, wether you define it on any instance of the class or not. One example might be the number of wheel for a vehicle, that could default to 4, for instance.
If later you write to this property :

```
 function Vehicle() {};
 Vehicle.protoype.wheelCount = 4;
 var myBike = new Vehicle();
 myBike.wheelCount = 2 ;           // this is a bike.
```

You won't change the value set on the prototype, but rather you'll create a new property on the instance, having the new value, so for instance :

```
 var myCar = new Vehicle();
 myCar.wheelCount // === 4
```

Now the very scenario you mention -setting a default value, and setting also an instance value in the constructor - doesn't make much sense, since you will have to use Object.getPrototypeOf to get to reach the default value. This is just a possibility that is of no use, just like there are many in all languages.